# how to import android licensed project in eclipse?

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to know how to import licensed project, while trying... the following classes cannot be imported.

```
import com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;
import com.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
```

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please refer this link [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html).

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of the LVL seems to require

```
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
```

instead of

```
import com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
...
```

(as the current document tells me to do)

It took me a half day to figure this out..  haha

Answer (score 2):

LVL library can be downloaded using the SDK Manager
[Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#download-lvl)

The License Verification Library (LVL) is a collection of helper classes that greatly simplify the work that you need to do to add licensing to your application. In all cases, we recommend that you download the LVL and use it as the basis for the licensing implementation in your application.

The LVL is available as a downloadable component of the Android SDK. The component includes:

The LVL sources, stored inside an Android library project.
An example application called "sample" that depends on the LVL library project. The example illustrates how an application uses the library helper classes to check and enforce licensing.
**To download the LVL component into your development environment, use the Android SDK and AVD Manager. Launch the Android SDK and AVD Manager and then select the "Market Licensing" component, as shown in the figure below. Accept the terms and click Install Selected to begin the download.**

Comment: What if the Market Licensing (now called Google Market per the linked site) is missing from the list?